# Как зафиксировать кнопку снизу экрана так, чтобы при прокрутке вниз до нахождения самой кнопки, она откреплялась? Position: sticky - не получается

Tags: javascript, html, css

мне нужно сделать в телефонной версии прикрепленную кнопку снизу экрана, но после прокрутки до нахождения той кнопки, чтобы она оставалась в своем же блоке, то-есть откреплялась

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Собственно, у меня есть кнопка покупки и я хочу, чтобы она ездила с экраном(снизу), до того момента, пока пользователь не дойдет до самой кнопки, которая находится снизу страницы. В этот момент она открепляется и остается в месте, там, где бы я ее не прикреплял снизу, а где она находится сейчас, то-есть до своего месторасположения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать Intersection Observer для этого. Он позволяет отслеживать наложение элементов друг на друга и в том числе смотреть, показался/скрылся ли элемент на экране.

Вот тут подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Пример с кнопкой может быть таким:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

const FIXED_CLASS_NAME = "button_fixed";

function handleButtonInterSection(entries) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        button.classList.remove(FIXED_CLASS_NAME);
      } else {
        button.classList.add(FIXED_CLASS_NAME);
      }
    
  });
}

const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
  handleButtonInterSection,
  {
    threshold: 0
  }
);

intersectionObserver.observe(container);
```

```css
.button_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>

<div class="container">
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>

<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="text">text</p>
```

Comment: Вашу конструкцию с `if ... else` можно сократить до всего одной строки `button.classList.toggle(FIXED_CLASS_NAME, !entry.isIntersecting);`

Comment: Вообще я всегда думал, что такой вариант не сработает ибо элемент при прикреплении всегда виден на экране. Пожалуй добавлю себе в сохраненные)

Comment: 1. ого, не знал про второй аргумент у toggle

Comment: 2. сработает, потому что здесь отслеживается контейнер, а не сам элемент

Comment: А.. То есть, если мы будем отслеживать именно кнопку, то оно не будет работать?

Comment: Кнопка, да, она же всегда на экране и так, поэтому не будет триггерить обзервер, надо что-то другое придумывать